# Automatic file versioning on Linux

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

I want to do the following: when a file is changed then the old file should be backed up to another location with different name on Linux. E.g. whenever example.text is changed, at each change, new files should be created like this: example1.text, example2.text ...

Comment: Other than doing it yourself (renaming files as you are saving) or having some sort of regular backup system (like TimeMachine for MacOS)(or say every 5 minutes) I don't think AFAIK a system is that aware of files to do that itself. The answer might depend on what program you are using.

Comment: As far as i know you can't have this functionality natively. You can either use version control (git) or there might be filesystems with this functionality ?

Answer (score 1):

There are three good methods to do this:

1. If you use a GUI text editor such as **gedit/pluma** and enable the option `Create a backup copy of files before saving` in the preferences then your `example1.txt` is saved to `example1.txt~` upon save. You can enable this for **nano** with `nano -B example1.txt`. Additionally **cp** with `cp -b example1.txt example2.txt` will create `example1.txt~` as well.
2. Use a *cron job* to backup files in a directory regularly, you can even combine this with a *VCS*. I can include the script I use if you ask nicely.
3. Use a **VCS** directly such as **git** and commit your files on a local repository (you can even migrate it to a remote location later if you choose) anytime you alter them.

It's possible you are simply asking for a *log rotater*, in which case you can use the command `logrotate` with [details here](http://linuxers.org/howto/howto-use-logrotate-manage-log-files) and [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/)

Comment: OP hasn't specified much but as far as gedit goes, I use a plugin called "doublesave" that timestamps backups. I wrote about it in [How to enable Gedit autosave files with name of current system Date and Time](http://askubuntu.com/a/308256/25656).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming using ZFS is an option (available either through FUSE or natively on Linux), one way would be to use [ZFS automatic snapshots](http://mk01.github.io/zfs-auto-snapshot/) to achieve something close to what you want.

Older snapshots are destroyed so you would need some tuning if you really want to keep each and every file update.